# Need help finding what's wrong with my date range creation

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I use Lodash and Momentjs to create a JSON date range with this structure :
{"days":[], "months": []}

Problem is :

- At the moment dates are created but they are created more than necessary there is a lot of duplicates
- Problem applies for months array and days array

Was like 2 days on this method but can't find why it doesn't work.

```
var startDate = moment();
var endDate = moment().add(61, 'days');
var months = [];
var range = {};
range.days = [];
range.months = [];
var currDate = startDate.clone().startOf('day');
var lastDate = endDate.clone().startOf('day');

while (currDate.add(1, 'days').diff(lastDate) < 0) {
  var month = {};
  month.name = currDate.clone().format('MMMM');
  month.year = currDate.clone().format('YYYY');
  var currentMonthDaysInTotal = moment(month.year + "-" + moment().month(currDate), "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth();
  var daysIndex = 1;
  while (daysIndex <= currentMonthDaysInTotal) {
    var newDateForList = moment([month.year, moment().month(month.name).format('M'), daysIndex]);
    if (newDateForList >= startDate && newDateForList <= endDate) {
      range.days.push(newDateForList);
    }
    daysIndex++;
  }
  if (months.length === 0) {
    months.push(month);
  }
  //regarder avec mitch
  if (_.findIndex(range.months, function(o) {
      return o.name !== month.name;
    }) === -1) {
    range.months.push(month);
  }
}
console.log(range);
```

Here is a JSFiddle with my code for what I'm trying to do :
https://jsfiddle.net/Keldarne/LdLc6u0t/

Comment: Hi Joseph, what exactly do you want to achieve? Why would the range be an array? I think what you need might be extremely simple compared to this

Comment: @w3jimmy I must get an array like this because i have to populate a table like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bmur.png

I want to have month on upper <th> element and days under <th> used for month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this along the right lines of what you wanted?

```js
var startDate = moment();
var endDate = moment().add(61, 'days');
var months = [];
var range = {};
range.days = [];
range.months = [];
var currDate = startDate.clone().startOf('day');
var lastDate = endDate.clone().startOf('day');

var monthYear = undefined;
while (currDate.add(1, 'days').diff(lastDate) < 0) {
  range.days.push(currDate.clone());
  var month = currDate.clone().format('MMMM'),
      year = currDate.clone().format('YYYY');
  if( month.concat( year ) !== monthYear ){
    range.months.push({
      name: month,
      year: year
    });
  }
  monthYear = month.concat( year );
}
console.log(range);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do thank your for helping me out :D !

Comment: No problem! you may want to set startDate to `moment().subtract(1, 'days');` if you want to include today's date.